# Why won't Pokémon Go let me log in

Tags: pokemon-go

I've downloaded Pokémon go for 2 days now, and I have not even played yet. Because I get the message "Our servers are experiencing issues. Please come back Later". I've checked all the other sites, I used a google account instead but still get the message "Our servers are experiencing issues. Please come back Later". I've done everything. I wanna play this game all my friends are playing it but not me.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can't log in because, literally, their servers are experiencing issues. Please come back Later. It's not only you, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to your problem other than trying it over and over again...
Had the same problem yesterday on my way back home from work.
A quick google search for your problem would have showed you, that the servers are having trouble.

http://www.polygon.com/2016/7/7/12123750/pokemon-go-server-issues-ios-android-fix

http://www.news.com.au/technology/home-entertainment/gaming/apps/pokemon-go-users-unable-to-log-in-due-to-high-demand/news-story/248df3e35313e348aed2ae1d76c6ede4